# Multi-core/threaded particle simulations

Tags: particles, performance

Recently did a liquid splash via Gleb Alexandrovs tutorial.

So smoke + flow field + particles + meta-balls to get some sort of fluid splash going on.
Where I noticed, none of these processes are able to use multiple cores. Grinding my 6 core / 12 thread CPU to a worse experience than a heavily OC-ed 2 core little thing. Making the whole experience quite unpleasant if using more than 550K particles.

Is there a way to make Blender 2,78 use more cores outside of rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Blender particles and simulations are still badly optimized and mostly single-threaded with no GPU compute support. With time features are added and even now you can look into the [FLIP FLUIDS addon](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids-Beta). Multithreaded with OpenCL support, demo for tryout [here](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/FLIP-Fluids-Demo-Addon).

Another solution might be [DualSPhysics](http://dual.sphysics.org/) simulation engine, which is free, multi-threaded and even GPU accelerated. It's ease of use is not that great, there is no integration with Blender other than importing the simulation data and rendering with Cycles (there is [addon](https://github.com/EPhysLab-UVigo/VisualSPHysics) for that). It is integrated with [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/). Ooutside of that there is no GUI, some programmer knowledge required.

Full capable, easy to use and well optimized simulation apps cost $3000+, like Houdini, Bifrost, RealFlow, etc.

Comment: Thanks! 
FLIP FLUIDS addon looks promissing. While DualSPHysics looks like a good engine; having an AMD card, and added complications make me want to try the first option.

Will see if I can get it to run. Hope blender will be able to enable multi core/thread support in a few more of it's tools. Quite like playing around with it, pretty relaxing...except when it isn't :/

Answer (score 1):

**NO.**

Processes like render can be separated in different parts, as you can see as a tiles. But some processes (like the smooth) can't be divided into threads to use all the processor cores. In this case one thread use only 1 CPU core: 1/4 or 1/8 (depends of how many cores in your CPU) of all CPU power. If so, CPU monitor will show that only 25% or 12% of CPU is used.