# Dynamic paint simulations very slow on good hardware configuration

Tags: dynamic-paint

Have a question regarding dynamic simulations in blender 2.80 eevee.
I have a canvas from a plane 40x40m with 100 subdivisions, smooth sade and subdivision level of two.

My hardware:
CPU: AMD Threadripper 1950x 3.5 GB, 32 Threads
RAM: 64GB 3200
GPU: 2 X GPU 1080 TI 11GB

When I press play to simulate an dropping sphere in the water(the plane that has dynamic paint on it) is moving slower than a snail.

What could be the problem? Is there an workaround? Actually any simulations are going slow on my PC. What's wrong with my blender config, or hardware config?

Thx

Comment: I might be wrong, but Physics aren't multithreaded well, so doesn't utilize all CPU power. Might try to apply all modifiers before DP to save calculation time.

Comment: I hope you are not expecting a Houdini level performance from a free application.. Did the simulation in Blender work faster for you in 2.79 and in 2.8 got slower?

Comment: doesn't matter the version I'm using. Same results.
But, thx for the answer, I'll try the point with applying modifiers. And as far as Jaroslavsays, maybe I should stick with the idea that is an free software and I should wait for the developers to integrate multi-thred Physics or to forget about speed :))

Comment: You can check with system monitoring how much of your hw is being utilized. My quess is about 6% cpu and 0% gpu, Blender does not support OpenCL acceleration for simulations yet. There are some other alternatives: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102156/7777. Also Houdini Apprentice is free so you can evaluate it, it can even import/export .obj meshes.

Comment: Yes, Jaroslav, something like that. 6-8% usage. I'll check the solution provided by you in the link above. Thx again for support.